# If $\varphi[A]$ is bounded ($\forall\varphi$) then $A$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $E$ be a normed space over field $\mathbb{C}$ and $A$ a subset of $E$ such that    $\varphi[A]$ is bounded for all $\varphi\in E'$. How to prove that $A$ is bounded  applying Hahn-Banach Theorem and Uniform Boundedness Principle?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: identify $E$ with a subset of $E''$.  Then note that $A$ is a pointwise bounded set of continuous functionals on $E'$ and use the uniform boundedness principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the standard embedding $\varphi\colon E\mapsto E^{\ast\ast}$, where $\varphi(e)=\mathrm{ev}_e\colon E^{\ast}\to\Bbb R$, given by $\mathrm{ev}_e(\psi)=\psi(e)$ for all $\psi\in E^\ast$.

Now you can identify $A$ with $\varphi(A)\subseteq E^{\ast\ast}$ and note that $\mathrm{ev}_a\colon E^\ast\to\Bbb R$ is bounded for every $a\in A$, by hypothesis. By the uniform boundedness principle there is some $c\in\Bbb R$ with $\|\mathrm{ev}_a(\psi)\|\leq c\|\psi\|$ for all $a\in A$ and all $\psi\in E^\ast$.

But remembering that $$\|a\|=\sup_{\substack{\psi\in E^\ast \\ \|\psi\|=1}}\psi(a)$$
we get $\|a\|\leq c$ for all $a\in A$, so $A$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:By Hahn Banach for every $x$, you can extend $f_x(x)=\|x\|$ defined on $Vect(x)$ to $E$

Comment: $Vect(x)$ being...?

Comment: Thanks for your sugerence, but $f_x$ is a linear funcional?

Comment: @Chase or the set $Span\{x\}$.

Comment: @felipeuni I believe the span is a characteristic of a vector space, not a single vector, specifically for an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ with basis $B$ over a field $F$, $$\operatorname{span}(V)=\bigl\{v^1e_1+\cdots+v^ne_n:v^i\in F \wedge e_i\in B\bigr\}$$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor You can certainly take the span of a single vector, it generates a one-dimensional linear subspace.