# Do we have $K = \text{conv} \; (ext K)$? for convex, compact set $K$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Assume $K$ is compact, and convex subset of $X$.

My first question:  Do we have $K = \text{conv} \; (ext K)$?  where $ext K$ denotes the set of all extrem points of $K$.

My second and main question: Assume $K \subset X^*$ which is convex, norm bounded and weak* compact. Do we have $K = \text{conv} \; (ext K)$?

I think answer of the first question is NO. Because by Krein-Miliman Theorem we only can say  $K $ is the closure of $ \text{conv} \; (ext K)$ and I dont think being Banach is a bonus here.

Comment: Re question1: You're right, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047985/krein-milman-theorem-why-the-closed-convex-hull-is-needed) for an explicit example showing why taking the closure is necessary

Comment: Re question 2: Note that weak* compact implies norm bounded, so you have an unnecessary hypothesis

Comment: Thanks, Do you have a proof for your second statement ? @AlessandroCodenotti

Comment: Yes, the [argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288378/if-varphia-is-bounded-forall-varphi-then-a-is-bounded/3290221#3290221) used to prove that a weakly compact set is norm bounded can be used to show that the same holds for the weak* topology. In fact more can be said, in the weak* topology compact and norm bounded+weak* closed are equivalent, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439943/characterization-of-compactness-in-weak-topology)

Comment: Also I think that counterexamples to question two can be constructed in the same way as for question one, since $X^\ast$ with the weak topology (so with the weak* topology for a reflexive Banach space $X$) is a locally convex topological vector space.